# change the font in mobile site using bootstrap

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, webforms, webfonts

I am using bootstrap3.3.4 in visual studio 2013 to create a new webform application, and I deleted the Site.Mobile.Master file, to make sure my application is using the Site.Master only. I also updated the site.css to have new webfont style. i.e. Roboto, Raleway...

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,300,400);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500,400,300);

.lightFont {
    font-family:"Raleway";
    font-weight:300;
}
```

Let we say I have 2 h2 tags, where one of them is having the lightFont class:

```
<h2>Default header</h2> 
<h2 class="lightFont>Light Font header</h2>
```

I open the page on the computer browser, and everything was perfect. one normal header, and one light header

My Problem is when I tried it from my mobile, the font remains the same for both headers regardless of the style. It looks like there is a special place to change the font for mobiles.

So, is there any idea on where to define the font to be used on the mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of search and tests, I found that the following declaration will solve the problem. I don't have any justification or reason why the previous declaration didn't work, but the following is working on multiple devices.

First, you must have the font files in your application; in my case I put them in a folder called "fonts".

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    src: url('../fonts/raleway_thin-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/raleway_thin-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
        url('../fonts/raleway_thin-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
        url('../fonts/raleway_thin-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
        url('../fonts/raleway_thin-webfont.svg#webfontnF3kUzPR') format('svg');
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Now, you may ask why I repeat the 'src' property for the 'eot' extension. well, I just copy the declaration of the **glyphicons** font from the template created by visual studio 2013 (**bootstrap.css**).
so I just follow it blindly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've noticed, but you didn't close the string correctly in your HTML. You wrote `<h2 class="lightFont>`, but that should be `<h2 class="lightFont">`.

Comment: this was a typo mistake while writing this question. it's correct in the application. this has nothing to do with my question, as my concern is why mobile is not applying these styles while computer did.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px;){

.lightFont {
   font-family:"Raleway";
   font-weight:300;
   font-size:34px;
  }

 }
```

This will make the font bigger if the screen size is below 750px.

Comment: the amazing part is that the size increases, but the font "Raleway" was not applied. the default font remains. this was on mobile. but I resize chrome on windows to be less than 750, it changes both font and size.